# Vinted request blocked in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, axios

I want to do some requests on the Vinted website, I have a code python which works perfectly, but the "same" code in JavaScript doesn't. Vinted's Cloudflare block the request after 1 request, with the code 1020 (access denied).

I start my script with the command `node index.js`

Here is the python code

```
import requests;

headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({"User-agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
response = requests.get("https://www.vinted.fr/vetements?search_text=casquette&brand_id[]=362&order=newest_first&color_id[]=12", headers=headers)

print(response)

headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({"User-agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
response = requests.get("https://www.vinted.fr/vetements?search_text=casquette&brand_id[]=362&order=newest_first&color_id[]=12", headers=headers)

print(response)
```

And here the JS one

```
const config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://www.vinted.fr/vetements?search_text=casquette&brand_id[]=362&order=newest_first&color_id[]=12',
    headers: { 
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0', 
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 
      'Accept': '*/*', 
      'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    }
  };
  
axios(config).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    axios(config).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
})
```

The Vinted error is

```
<h1>Access denied</h1>
<p>You do not have access to www.vinted.fr.</p><p>The site owner may have set restrictions that prevent you from accessing the site. Contact the site owner for access or try loading the page again.</p>
<ul class="cferror_details">
<li>Ray ID: 7126ef811e8376e1</li>
<li>Timestamp: 2022-05-28 12:18:54 UTC</li>
<li>Your IP address: X.X.X.X</li>
<li class="XXX_no_wrap_overflow_hidden">Requested URL: www.vinted.fr/vetements?search_text=casquette&amp;brand_id[]=362&amp;order=newest_first&amp;color_id[]=12 </li>
<li>Error reference number: 1020</li>
<li>Server ID: FL_376F42</li>
<li>User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0</li>
```

Comment: Is this JS code being run serverside or client-side? If it's client-side you might be getting a CORS error (you can check your browser console for errors)

Comment: @NickParsons the code is runned server side I guess. I do `node index.js` to start it. The error is that the vented's Cloudflare block me. Here is the error :
`<li>Ray ID: 7126ef811e8376e1</li>\n' +      '    <li>Timestamp: 2022-05-28 2:18:54 UTC</li>\n' +      '    <li>Your IP address: X.X.X.X' +      '    <li lass="XXX_no_wrap_overflow_hidden">Requested URL: ww.vinted.fr/vetements?earch_text=casquette&amp;brand_id[]=362&amp;order=newest_first&amp;colo_id[]=12 </li>\n' +      Error reference number: 1020</li>\n' +      Server ID: L_376F42 +      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0`